# Dominant term in convergence in MSE

Tags: asymptotics, consistency, mse

The speed of convergence in MSE is typically dominated by the variance. 
Consider the ML estimator of the variance: Its variance decays as $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$ and the bias term decays as $\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$.

Would it be true to assert that the variance will always be the dominant term in the convergence rate?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure such a general statement can be made.
Consider the standard case of an i.i.d. sample of $n$ Uniforms $U(0,\theta)$. The MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat \theta = X_{(n)}$, the maximum order statistic, and consequently, the density of the MLE is

$$f(\hat \theta) = \frac {n}{\theta^n}\hat \theta^{n-1}$$

So

$$E(\hat \theta^2) = \int_{0}^{\theta}\hat \theta^2\frac {n}{\theta^n}\hat \theta^{n-1}d\hat \theta = \frac {n}{(n+2)\theta^n}\hat \theta^{n+2}\Big|_0^{\theta} = \frac {n}{n+2}\theta^2$$

and

$$E(\hat \theta) = \int_{0}^{\theta}\hat \theta\frac {n}{\theta^n}\hat \theta^{n-1}d\hat \theta = \frac {n}{(n+1)\theta^n}\hat \theta^{n+1}\Big|_0^{\theta} = \frac {n}{n+1}\theta$$

Therefore

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat \theta) = E(\hat \theta^2) -[E(\hat \theta)]^2 = \frac {n}{n+2}\theta^2 - \left(\frac {n}{n+1}\right)^2\theta^2 = \frac n{(n+2)(n+1)^2}\theta^2$$

while

$$[B(\hat \theta)]^2 = \left (E(\hat \theta) - \theta\right)^2 = \left (\frac {n}{n+1} - 1\right)^2\theta^2 = \frac 1{(n+1)^2}\theta^2$$

So both are $\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$ here.

Comment: The natural next stage is to look for an example where the bias dominates...

Comment: Hmm, can this happen? It may be the case after all, that the variance "weakly dominates" the rate of convergence of MSE.

Comment: The uniform distribution is a somewhat unusual (but perfectly legitimate, of course!) counterexample in that it is not a "regular" estimation problem as the support of the distribution depends on the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: @ChristophHanck True. This might have something to do with the result, and the conjecture of the question could hold generally enough. Informally, the increasing sample size first centers the distribution, and then sets out to collapse it... yes it makes sense that it can hold in many cases.

Comment: @ChristophHanck CONTD ...because when the true value is at the boundary, the distribution of the estimator cannot be "centered" around the true value, while if it is say, asymptotically normal, it can.

Answer (score 1):

A late reply, but nevertheless. In nonparametric statistic, the rate of the bias of a kernel point-estimator of a density is $O(h^4)$ and of the variance, it is $O(1/(nh))$, where $n$ is the sample size and $h$ the bandwidth. This implies that the which term dominates depends on our choice. If we choose $h$ to go very quickly to zero, then the variance is the dominating part (undersmooth case). If we oversmooth, then the bias dominates.